# best practice dealing with non persistent properties, frequent updates

Tags: swift3, realm

i am new to realm and did not found a solution which was satisfies me.

i have an application where i can record tours with gps data and so on. (there are multiple different objects which are stored in realm). 
i created a realm singleton which should do all my realm suff (update, create, delete) for my objects.

now i ran into the following problem:
i start a tour and record it. first it is created, everything is fine. then i came to the point where i have to update my tour object and only a few properties (basically each new gps point updates it). an additional requirement is, that there can be properties, which are not persistent in realm and are only on the object instance.

so now i have the options to call realm.add(object, update:true) which overrides all properties.
i cannot say object.prop1 = asdf , object.pro2 = 345 because i have no write context at this level of my logic. so i can update within a realm.create(type, updatedict, update:true) 
but the big downside of this approach is, that i have to refetch the object again to "know" the changes on my object instance.

so updating some properties of an object results in:
create dictionary with id(primary key) and properties to change
call update on my realm singleton and passing all necessary data.
call a fetch on my realm instance to get the new object again, which leads me to loose existing not persisted property values.

i doubt i'm the first with such a requirement but i could not find a solution:

Summary:
Realm Singleton class handling all Realm actions within a write context
Different Realm Object classes which can have not persistent objects
Need partially update for some properties
dont want to have realm code in my viewcontrollers logic, only in its manager.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to suggest something without any code examples but personally I think not having the ability to update the individual properties of your models is not a good idea.

I think you have 2 options:

1. Add a method to your `RealmSingleton` that allows you to get write context (to execute a block inside a write transaction), like:

   ```
   func updateTour(updateBlock: (Tour) -> Void) {
       realm.write {
           updateBlock(currentTour)
       }
   }

   ...

   RealmSingleton.shared.updateTour { tour in
       tour.property = value
   }
   ```
2. Add the convenience methods to update the individual properties of your `Tour` object:

   ```
   RealmSingleton.shared.setTourProperty(value)
   ```